# Простейшая реализация поиска совпадений строк или их частей

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, поисковые-системы, hql

Есть небольшое веб-приложение.

Есть `Adverts`(объявления) с `title`(название) и `body`(описание)

Как, используя hibernate (или хотя бы native slq), можно реализовать функцию поиска объявлений.
Чтобы с запросом приходила строка и база искала совпадений.

Есть идея доставать все объявления и по ним уже встроенными в Java средствами искать, но это плохо, дорого и не правильно.

Пример запрос: машина

Примет выдачи:

```
1.                               2.
title: Продам машину             title: Игрушки
body: null                       body: в наличии машинки, куклы, бусы
```

Comment: Ну это полнотекстовый поиск - встроенными или внешними средствами.

Comment: @Akina, а можно чуток подробнее? Мб ссылки какие почитать, или хотя бы названия некоторых средств?

Comment: @Akina, нашёл, почитал, спасибо за наводку. Но полнотекстовой поиск ищет только полное совпадение, хотелось бы ещё иметь и поиск на содержание строки в строке

Answer (score 1):

Например, если нейтив sql всё-таки подойдет, можно разбивать каждое поле где есть текст, который необходимо обработать, на слова (в англоязычном SO есть [вот такой пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)), а затем, к каждому слову применить функцию [расстояния левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), которая в [mysql вроде как тоже есть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909885/how-to-add-levenshtein-function-in-mysql).

Соотв-но, задав некий порог "похожести" можно принимать решение о том, есть ли заданное слово в каком-то виде или какой-то форме в искомом тексте.